Transaction execution reverted on swapExactTokensForETH
I hope somebody can help
I am trying to sell a token via Uniswap V2 Router02 (Token CA: 0x4ed4E862860beD51a9570b96d89aF5E1B0Efefed) (This token is a legit one, there is no scam here), I have successfully bought it using swapExactETHForTokens: Base Scan
But when it comes to swapExactTokensForETH, though I approved the spending token to Uniswap V2 Router02: Base Scan, the transaction always gets reverted!: Base Scan
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { fs } = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();
const SWAP_ROUTER02_ABI = require("./ABIs/UniswapV2Router02.json");
const ERC20_ABI = require("./ABIs/ERC20.json");

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.BASE_RPC);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

const SWAP_ROUTER02_ADDRESS = "0x4752ba5dbc23f44d87826276bf6fd6b1c372ad24";
const WETH_ADDRESS = "0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006";
const TOKEN_ADDRESS = "0x4ed4E862860beD51a9570b96d89aF5E1B0Efefed";

const erc20 = new ethers.Contract(TOKEN_ADDRESS, ERC20_ABI, signer);

const router = new ethers.Contract(
  SWAP_ROUTER02_ADDRESS,
  SWAP_ROUTER02_ABI,
  signer
);

async function sell() {
  const balance = await erc20.balanceOf(signer.address);
  console.log(balance);
  const approveTokenTx = await erc20.approve(
    "0x4752ba5dbc23f44d87826276bf6fd6b1c372ad24",
    ethers.parseEther("10000000000000")
  );
  const receipt1 = await approveTokenTx.wait();
  console.log(receipt1);

  const params = {
    amountIn: ethers.parseEther(balance.toString()),
    amountOutMin: 0,
    path: [TOKEN_ADDRESS, WETH_ADDRESS],
    to: signer.address,
    deadline: Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 * 20,
  };

  const tx = await router.swapExactTokensForETH(
    params.amountIn - params.amountIn / BigInt(2),
    params.amountOutMin,
    params.path,
    params.to,
    params.deadline,
    {
      gasLimit: 300000,
    }
  );
  const receipt = await tx.wait();
  console.log(receipt.hash);
}
sell();

What might go wrong here?

It says ERC20InsufficientBalance.
Are you meaning to pass that amountIn? 4878975283589739380.500000000000000000
Seems you don't actually have that number of token to move.
"value":"4878975283589739380500000000000000000",
"from":"0xc6487276cd76df5075125c90c524ebcf6be901bb"
"to":"0x7c327d692b72f60b28aecedbcc1ba784712fe7b2"

Seems you have 9.757950567179478761

*10**18 =9757950567179478761


Use that number.

Thank you so much!

@duyanhhz Much love
